# Jenkins: trigger a job with buildWithParameters gives white/blank screen

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins version 1.567.  I am trying to launch a Jenkins job from a URL by calling the buildWithParameters option.

My URL is set up like:

```
http://myjenkinsserver:8090/job/pc_test/buildWithParameters?token=PC123&Parm1=1
```

The job triggers perfectly well, however, I am presented with a blank, white screen.  So I do not know if the job has succeeded or not unless I manually logon to Jenkins.  This did not used to happen. Previously it would show the project page and I would be able to see the status of my job.

But I am not sure what has changed to make a blank page appear.

Can anyone suggest a solution whereby I can trigger the job via a URL and then see the results of the job?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22865

Answer (score 1):

A suitable workaround is using the [build-with-parameters plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters).

Change the URL to:

`http://myjenkinsserver:8090/job/pc_test/`**`parambuild`**`?token=PC123&Parm1=1`

This will show you a page with the chosen build parameters. You need to confirm by clicking the `Build` button. Afterwards you are redirected to the project page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `POST` request to `http://myjenkinsserver:8090/job/pc_test/build` with `json` (value must be **url encoded**) parameter in the request body. The body for your example is (not url encoded yet so it's easy to read):

`json={"parameter": {"name": "Parm1", "value": "1"}, "statusCode": "303", "redirectTo": "."}`

and here is url encoded version(use this one):

`json=%7B%22parameter%22%3A%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Parm1%22%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%221%22%7D%2C%20%22statusCode%22%3A%20%22303%22%2C%20%22redirectTo%22%3A%20%22.%22%7D`

Also make sure that you set `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Full example using curl:

`curl --data "json=on=%7B%22parameter%22%3A%20%7B%22name%22%3A%20%22Parm1%22%2C%20%22value%22%3A%20%221%22%7D%2C%20%22statusCode%22%3A%20%22303%22%2C%20%22redirectTo%22%3A%20%22.%22%7D" http://myjenkinsserver:8090/job/pc_test/build --verbose`

Answer (score -1):

Once you trigger the job, you can check its status using the Jenkins API.

See `http://your-jenkins-host/api/` for more details. Look into the documentations.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Manually checking the results is also possible by going to the project page. The OP wants to avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but there is still fairly sparse information on this.

This is a sample of adding a "Deploy" button to the Build Description on Jenkins 2.89.4:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Sample') {
      steps {
        sh 'echo "Sample"'
      }
    }
    post {
      success {
        script {
          currentBuild.description = "<form method='post' action='/job/sine-deploy/build'><input name='json' type='hidden' value=\"{'parameter': {'name': 'TRIGGERED_FROM_BUILD', 'runId': '${JOB_NAME}#${BUILD_NUMBER}'}, 'statusCode': '303', 'redirectTo': '/job/sine-deploy/'}\" /><input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Deploy' class='submit-button primary' /></form>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Safe HTML needs to be turned on for the form to work.

Comment: This is another way to trigger a build. But no forwarding from the blank buildWithParameters URL as asked by the OP.